# Find and Count Strings in a String then Display the String with the Highest Count

Tags: php, string, count

I have this mostly working, but I feel like there has to be a better way of doing it.

On the site there are ~60 horse breeds. Some horses are "purebred" and some are "crossbred". The purebreds I don't have an issue with, but for the crosses I need to figure out which breed they most closely resemble in order to display an image for that horse.

The images are set up like this: horse-Arabian-breed.png with some PHP and SQL pulling the horse's breed information down from the database and plugging the breed in between "horse-" and "-breed.png".

The crosses on the site are shown like this "Arabian x Dutch Warmblood" which obviously doesn't work well for the images. My plan is to look at the current horse, its mother and father, and it's four grand parents, get all of their breeds, figure out which breed has the most influence, and then use the image for that breed.

Here's what I currently have:

```
echo "Start horse breed: $horse_breed <br>";
echo "Sire  breed: $sire_breed <br>";
echo "Dam breed: $dam_breed <br>";
echo "Sire Sire breed: $sire_sire_breed <br>";
echo "Sire Dam breed: $sire_dam_breed <br>";
echo "Dam Sire breed: $dam_sire_breed <br>";
echo "Dam Dam breed: $dam_dam_breed <br>";
echo "<br><br>";

$hb = strval($horse_breed);
$sb = strval($sire_breed);
$db = strval($dam_breed);
$ssb = strval($sire_sire_breed);
$sdb = strval($sire_dam_breed);
$dsb = strval($dam_sire_breed);
$ddb = strval($dam_dam_breed);

$breed_hist = $hb.$sb.$db.$ssb.$sdb.$dsb.$ddb; 

echo $breed_hist; // outputs: Arabian x ThoroughbredArabianThoroughbredRetiredRetiredThoroughbredThoroughbred

echo "<br>";

$clean_hist = str_replace(" x ", "", $breed_hist);

echo $clean_hist; // outputs: ArabianThoroughbredArabianThoroughbredRetiredRetiredThoroughbredThoroughbred

echo "<br>";

$Arabian = substr_count($clean_hist, 'Arabian');
echo "Arabian: $Arabian"; // output: 2
echo "<br>";

$Thoroughbred = substr_count($clean_hist, 'Thoroughbred');
echo "Thoroughbred: $Thoroughbred"; // output: 4
echo "<br>";

$Warlander = substr_count($clean_hist, 'Warlander');
echo "Warlander: $Warlander"; // output: 0
echo "<br>";`
```

Above all of this I have some basic SQL pulling info from the database.

I know that you can use max() in PHP to find the highest value, but I'm not sure how to link the highest value with the right breed (I'm guessing a dictionary would work?).

For testing purposes I've been using:

Start horse breed: Arabian x Thoroughbred

Sire breed: Arabian

Dam breed: Thoroughbred

Sire Sire breed: Retired

Sire Dam breed: Retired

Dam Sire breed: Thoroughbred

Dam Dam breed: Thoroughbred

Retired means there's no more info on their breed so that one is ignored, which is fine.

The other thing I'm trying to figure out is how to randomly select between two or more breeds if there are multiples that tie for the highest.

Any tips on how I can do this cleaner and/or easier would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, a dictionary does work. In PHP that is an array: http://php.net/array - You will make your life more easy anyway to use an array here for all those breads instead of the different variables for the breeds. You need some pointers?

Comment: I agree that the cleanest way would be to use arrays to track the breed history for a given horse. Using scalars like you are now, you would need to loop through each breed type and track the max count returned by substr_count along with the associated breed type.

Comment: A PHP database like MySQL would suffice, eh?

Comment: @hakre, Thanks. I'll switch over to an array. Any pointers for this would be great.

The breeds are already in a database with the associated horse, which is why it works just fine for the purebred horses. It's when the horse is something like "Arabian x Thoroughbred" that I need to figure out what's the main breed for the horse.

Comment: The list is too long to fit in here, but here's some of them: Akhal Teke,
American Paint Horse,
American Quarter Horse,
American Saddlebred,
Andalusian,
Anglo-Arabian,
Appaloosa,
Arabian,
Ardennais,
Australian Brumby,
Australian Stock Horse,
Azteca,
Bashkir Curly,
Belgian Draft,
British Riding Pony,
Chincoteague Pony,
Cleveland Bay,
Clydesdale,
Connemara Pony,
Criollo,
Dales Pony,
Dartmoor Pony,
Dutch Warmblood,
Exmoor Pony,
Fell Pony,
Friesian,
Gypsy Vanner,
Hackney,
Hanoverian,
Highland Pony,
Holsteiner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this gives you some pointers, creating arrays upfront that define the data that is actually used. Those are then helpful to obtain the information you're looking for. Because those are arrays, most things can be done in an iterative fashion (see [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) and that normally rocks. I use it actually two times, first time to create the history, second time to find out which breed is top-count:

```
$breeds = ['Arabian', 'Retired', 'Thoroughbred', 'Warlander'];

$breed_combos = [
    'horse'     => 'Start horse',
    'sire'      => 'Sire',
    'dam'       => 'Dam',
    'sire_sire' => 'Sire Sire',
    'sire_dam'  => 'Sire Dam',
    'dam_sire'  => 'Dam Sire',
    'dam_dam'   => 'Dam Dam',
];


// combine history
$horse_breed_history = '';
foreach ($breed_combos as $breed_combo_key => $breed_combo_label) {
    $variable = sprintf("%s_breed", $breed_combo_key);
    $breed    = isset($$variable) ? $$variable : random_breed(); # you have the variable set
    printf("%' 12s breed: %s\n", $breed_combo_label, $breed);
    $horse_breed_history .= str_replace(' x ', '', $breed);
}
echo '           History: ', $horse_breed_history, "\n";


// count and pick highest
$horse_breed_history_main = (object)['count' => -1];
foreach ($breeds as $breed) {
    $count = substr_count($horse_breed_history, $breed);
    if ($count > $horse_breed_history_main->count) {
        $horse_breed_history_main->breed = $breed;
        $horse_breed_history_main->count = $count;
    }
}
echo '         Top breed: ', $horse_breed_history_main->breed, "\n";
```

Some exemplary (I use random values here because I don't have the database nor was I sure about all breeds):

```
 Start horse breed: Thoroughbred x Retired
        Sire breed: Warlander
         Dam breed: Retired
   Sire Sire breed: Retired x Arabian
    Sire Dam breed: Retired
    Dam Sire breed: Arabian
     Dam Dam breed: Retired x Warlander
           History: ThoroughbredRetiredWarlanderRetiredRetiredArabianRetiredArabianRetiredWarlander
         Top breed: Retired
```

These breeds and the history probably does not make much sense, but it should show how it works.

I don't know what your database structure is, probably you can also do this in the database with some query which in the end would be best probably. If not, this example shows how to deal with the string counts and getting the top count while iterating over all possible breeds.

BTW if you concatenate with a space, you could create strings that are better separated:

```
" Arabian Arabian Retired Thoroughbred Retired Warlander Arabian Thoroughbred Warlander "
```

Allowing to `explode` on the separation character (space here), and then counting the actual values with `array_count_values` and then sorting descending with `arsort` and then the first entry is the highest:

```
$string = " Arabian Arabian Retired Thoroughbred Retired Warlander Arabian Thoroughbred Warlander ";
$values = array_count_values(explode(' ', trim($string)));
arsort($values);
print_r($values);
```

I would say this is the best for PHP in your case, if you can not do it in the database.

```
Array
(
    [Arabian] => 3
    [Warlander] => 2
    [Retired] => 2
    [Thoroughbred] => 2
)
```

Here is the code-block from above adopted to create the space-separated list:

```
// combine history
$horse_breed_history = ' ';
foreach ($breed_combos as $breed_combo_key => $breed_combo_label) {
    $variable = sprintf("%s_breed", $breed_combo_key);
    $breed    = isset($$variable) ? $$variable : random_breed(); # you have the variable set
    printf("%' 12s breed: %s\n", $breed_combo_label, $breed);
    $horse_breed_history .= str_replace(' x ', ' ', $breed) . ' ';
}
echo '           History: ', $horse_breed_history, "\n";
```

It just addas a space at the very beginning and then after adding an element. Also the replacement of `x` has been changed to keep one space.

I hope this gives some pointers and you can pick something useful out of it.

Comment: Thanks, this looks really good (and your explanation is great!). I seem to be having an issue with the brackets though []. I keep getting errors about them. Is there a particular PHP version I need to use for this?

Comment: I changed the brackets to arrays and had to comment out a line ($horse_breed_history_main = (object)['count' => -1];), but it seems to be functioning. What is that one line for?

Comment: Okay, the brackets: That is PHP 5.4 notation for array, when you got lower PHP version `[ ... ]` is `array( ... )` - then your error should go away. See http://php.net/arrays the *Example #1 A simple array* shows both variants next to each other.

Comment: That `= (object)` line is casting an array into an object. That's just a simple way to create a new `stdClass` with a property. Alternative you can do: `$horse_breed_history_main = (object)array('count' => -1);` or the longer version: `$horse_breed_history_main = new stdClass(); $horse_breed_history_main->count = -1;` which better shows what this does (new stdClass + setting the count property to -1)

Comment: Thanks a ton. I'm making a few changes to your code, but you helped out _SO much_ and your explanations were great. Thank you very much. (: